# Formal Proof - Premises & Conclusion (Rules of Inference & Equivalence)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So I have gathered/learned a total of 8 different rules of inference & 10 rules of equivalence for proofs: making a total of 18 proofs (Modus Ponens, Modus Tollens, Disjunctive Syllogism, Hypothetical Syllogism, Conjunction, Addition, Simplification, Constructive Dilemma, De Morgan's Law, Association, Distribution, Commutativity, Double Negation, Contraposition, Material Implication, Material Equivalence, Expotation, and Tautology). I want to turn the following premises GIVEN into a conclusion using the rules I know and mentioned.

Premises:

1. $(G \wedge I) \implies H$
2. $(I \implies H) \implies F$

**Conclusion [What I want]** : $G\implies F$

**My Progress** :

1. $(G \wedge I) \implies H$
2. $(I \implies H) \implies F\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad [ G \implies F]$
3. $G \implies (I \implies H)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad [1, $exp]
4. $\sim(I \implies H) \vee F\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\;    [2, $Impl]

Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 2):

> So I have gathered/learned a total of 8 different rules of inference & 10 rules of equivalence for proofs: making a total of 18 proofs (Modus Ponens, Modus Tollens, Disjunctive Syllogism, **Hypothetical Syllogism**, Conjunction, Addition, Simplification, Constructive Dilemma, De Morgan's Law, Association, Distribution, Commutativity, Double Negation, Contraposition, Material Implication, Material Equivalence, Expotation, and Tautology).

[Hypothetical Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism) is the rule of inference you seek:$$\dfrac{\phi\to\psi\qquad \psi\to\rho}{\phi\to\rho}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the first premise, we can find an equivalence :
$$
(G \wedge I) \implies H \equiv (G\implies H)\vee (I\implies H)
$$
We have that from second premise $(I \implies H) \implies F$ so notice that :
$$
[(I \implies H)\wedge[(I \implies H) \implies F]]\implies F\qquad\text{[Modus Ponens]}
$$
Therefore :
$$
(G \wedge I) \implies H \equiv (G\implies F)\vee F$$
Which means $G\implies F$.

Comment: What rules were followed if I may ask? The issue is I need to follow the rules mentioned to get to the conclusion. Note: The [⟹] is next to the 2nd premise to show that the premises given are what I use along with the rules.

Comment: The first one I do not recall it has a specific name as for the remaining equivalences  I applied modus ponens since  $[I \implies H]$ and $[I \implies H]\implies F$ would imply $F$

Comment: I have edited my question and showed how I used Modus Ponens.

Comment: Correction : answer*